# How to calculate an integral using Leibnitz rule

Tags: calculus, integration

I would like to calculate these two integrals using Leibnitz's rule of differentiating under the integral sign:

$$\frac{d^2}{dx^2}\int_{0}^{t} \int_{x-c(t-\tau)}^{x+c(t-\tau)} h(\theta, \tau) d\theta d\tau$$
$$\frac{d^2}{dt^2}\int_{0}^{t} \int_{x-c(t-\tau)}^{x+c(t-\tau)} h(\theta, \tau) d\theta d\tau$$
 Thanks in advance

Comment: Hello. Can you include in your post where you are having difficulties?

Comment: Thank you for your attention. I posted that way because I am not very sure about the steps I follow. That's why I would like to see the hole process of calculus.

Answer (score 3):

$$\begin{align}
\frac{d^2}{dx^2}\int_{0}^{t} \int_{x-c(t-\tau)}^{x+c(t-\tau)} h(\theta, \tau) d\theta d\tau&=\frac{d}{dx}\int_{0}^{t}\frac{d}{dx} \int_{x-c(t-\tau)}^{x+c(t-\tau)} h(\theta, \tau) d\theta d\tau\\\\
&=\frac{d}{dx}\int_{0}^{t}(h(x+c(t-\tau), \tau)-h(x-c(t-\tau), \tau))d\tau\\\\
&\int_{0}^{t}(h_1(x+c(t-\tau), \tau)-h_1(x-c(t-\tau), \tau))d\tau
\end{align}$$

where $h_1$ designates the partial derivative with respect to the first argument.